# java is it bad to declare a variable of type E (generics)

Tags: java, generics

I'm looking at an example implementation of a linkedlist consisting of nodes. The set method goes to the input index and sets the value equal to the input value. Additionally, it returns the old value.  When he retrieves the old value he always creates a new node object instead of an object of type E. Is that necessary or is that considered good practice? Also are there any efficiency considerations? Example code below

```
public E set(int idx, E newVal){

    //looping code to get to the right node
    //Assume variable finger is now a Node object that's at the right index

    Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(finger);
    finger.setValue(newVal);
    return temp.getValue();

    //Can I do the following instead?
    E temp = finger.getValue();
    finger.setValue(newVal);
    return temp;

 }
```

Comment: The first approach doesn't look correct to me.  You're calling `getValue()` on an object *after* you call `setValue()`, so I imagine that would return the *new* value.

Comment: yea sorry i was typing it in and typed wrong he creates a new node. I'll edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's perfectly acceptable to use the generic type parameter (`E` in this case).  There's nothing wrong with your second code sample.

According to [the Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ200):

> **Can I use a type parameter like a type?**
>
> *No, a type parameter is not a type in the regular sense (different from a regular type such as a non-generic class or interface).*
>
> Type parameters can be used for typing (like non-generic classes and interfaces)::
>
> - as argument and return types of methods
> - **as type of a field or local reference variable**
> - as type argument of other parameterized types
> - as target type in casts
> - as explicit type argument of parameterized methods
>
> Type parameters can NOT be used for the following purposes (different from non-generic classes and interfaces)::
>
> - for creation of objects
> - for creation of arrays
> - in exception handling
> - in static context
> - in instanceof expressions
> - as supertypes
> - in a class literal

Comment: Well, anywhere except e.g. `new E`!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `setValue()` and `getValue()` modify the same attribute, the first 3 lines of code will return `newVal` (they don't make much sense)

`temp` is a reference to `finger`, so if you set a new value to an attribute in `finger`, then it will change in `temp`.

The last three lines don't have the same behavior, since they return the previous value.

Comment: Ahh! ok, in this case, you'll have the same behavior, but the last three lines are more readable and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

That impl is quite odd. It probably was translated from a C++ impl

```
Node<E> temp = finger; // C++, copy constructor, default is shallow copy
finger.setValue(newVal);
return temp.getValue();
```

That would be very cheap for C++.